# How to calculate taylor series and Lewis Carrol divisbilty test in python 3.5 without using the math module

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, taylor-series

Like the title says, I need to find Taylor series as well as program the divisibility test without using the math module in Python 3.5. I'd do the math on a piece of paper but I was actually never taught either one of these things in school so I honestly have absolutely no clue how to the hell do them on paper. I have a fair amount of it done, but I need some help finishing it. I have had a friend teach me about the algorithms used to program this, so I'm slightly more knowledgeable about this now. See the really long comment for my main programming problem that I'm encountering.

For Taylor Series: In computing the value of [image: e^x]/sin x/cos x, your program should continue to add terms of the power series until it reaches a term whose absolute value is less than [image: 10^-15] times the absolute vale of the sum of the previous terms.

Formulas:

[image: e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ...]

[image: cos x = 1- x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x6^/6! …]

[image: sin x = sin x = x- x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7!...]

If n is a positive integer:
    n! = n x( n-1) x (n-2) x…x 3 x 2 x 1

For Lewis Carrol divisibility test:

- As long as the number has more than one digit, shorten it by deleting the units digit and subtracting this digit from the resulting number.
- The original number is divisible by 11 if and only if the final number is equal to zero

CODE:

```
 #I don't know why, but for some reason n is automatically set to 5 once it is called in the recursion function for sin and cos x.
 #This causes the answers to for sin and cos x to be drastically incorrect.

 x = float(input("Please input a real number: "))
 def factorial(n):
      res = 1
      for i in range(1, n+1):
           res *= i
      return res

 def question1():
      ex = 1 + x
      for n in range(2,15):
          ex += (x**n)/factorial(n)
      print("e^{} = {}".format(x, ex))
 question1()

 def question2(): 
      cosx = 0
      for n in range(0, 15):
           cosx += ((-1)**n)/factorial(2*n)*(x**(2*n+1))
      print("cos {} = {}".format(x, cosx))
 question2()

 def question3():
      sinx = 0
      for n in range(0, 15):
           sinx += ((-1)**n)/factorial(2*n+1)*(x**(2*n+1)) 
      print("Sin {} = {}".format(x, sinx))
 question3()

 ##def question4():
 ##     while x > 9:
 ##          unit = x % 10
 ##          new_x = x // 10
 ##          print(new_x)
 ##          if new_x == 0:
 ##               break
 ##question4()
```

Sample output:

```
Please input a real number: 10
e^10.0 = 20188.170595424563
cos 10.0 = -10962.271813947433
Sin 10.0 = -1083.6650211561773
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
...
```

Comment: "I'd do the math on a piece of paper but I was actually never taught either one of these things in school so I honestly have absolutely no clue how to the hell do them on paper." - then step one should be to learn those things.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Comment: In particular, you need to learn the algorithms used before you can program them.  StackOverflow is not a place to receive such tutorials.  Once you've done that, *assuming* you hit a programming problem, please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Your posted code ignores the accuracy specification, and your cosine function is simply the e^x function + 1.

Comment: *Aside*: the algorithm, as stated, will not complete for `sin(0)`.

Comment: Ben, it isn't clear exactly what your question is. Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site. In order for this format to work, you have to ask a question, so that others can answer it. What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: My question is how to fix the odd problem that I'm running into as well as how to get the functions working properly.

Comment: Can you expand, in your post, on that question? For example, what does "suddenly defined as 5" mean?

Comment: Also, did you copy-paste that code into your question, or did you retype it? (Please copy-paste it from your actual program.) Your code has a syntax error, which means that you've never run the code as it appears in the question.

Comment: While running, the value of n changes from being set as 2 in the for loop, to being set as 5 once the program reaches the line res = 1 in the factorial function. This only happens while the program is running through those 2 functions. question1() runs perfectly. If you have IDLE installed, you can run the debugger and replicate the problem. step until prompted for input, press out to input the float, then continue stepping until you find the problem that I'm encountering with this.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation in the `for` loop in your `question3()` function has a number of errors.

- In `(-1**n)`, the `**` has higher precedence than `-`. The correct expression is `((-1)**n)`
- In the divisor, `(x*(2*n)+1)` uses multiplication instead of exponentiation. Should be: `x**(...`, not `x*(...`.
- In the divisor, the `*` (corrected to `**`) has higher precedence than `+1`. Should be: `(x**(2*n+1))`.
- The `n -= 1` has no effect, since `n` is immediately rebound to a new value at the top of the next iteration of the loop.
- The loop iterator should start at zero, not two.

Old:

```
 for n in range(2, 15): #n is defined as 2 here
     sinx += (-1**n)/factorial((2*n+1))*(x*(2*n)+1)
     n -= 1
```

Better:

```
 for n in range(0, 15): #n is defined as 2 here
     sinx += ((-1)**n)/factorial(2*n+1)*(x**(2*n+1))
```

You still have a logic error. The assignment requires that you terminate the loop when an individual term is smaller than `10**-15` times the preceding sum. You didn't implement that at all.

`question2()` contains these errors:

- `-1**n` should be `(-1)**n`
- You have an extraneous `+1` in your divisor.
- You have a meaningless `n -= 1` in your loop.

Try this:

```
def question2():
     cosx = 0
     for n in range(0, 15):
          cosx += ((-1)**n)/factorial((2*n))*(x**(2*n))
     print(cosx)
```

Comment: I'll look at question2 next.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions, and, they've gotten me much closer to it being correct, though the answer for cos is still fairly off. Sin is much closer.

Output:

`cos 10.0 = -8.356502175518944`
`sin 10.0 = -0.5429111519642775`

Comment: Implementing all your suggestions has made the cos and sin functions work properly. All I need now is to fix up question4 and this will be done.